# React Native release build crashes on launch (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Experiencing this silent crash with this error on XCode:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._propsAnimated.setNativeView')

This error is located at:
in n
in t
in n
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
in RCTView
in n
in r
in Unknown
in t
in a
in RCTView
in t
in Styled(t)
in Unknown
in g
in RCTView
in l
in RCTView
in RootSiblingsWrapper
in RCTView
in t',
```

Not sure what to do.

Node: 8.4.0
npm: 5.5.1
Watchman: 4.7.0
react: ^16.3.0-alpha.1
react-native: ^0.54.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We experienced this when upgrading React Native, something to do with the *libRCTAnimation.a*. Reinstalled everything, *npm install* and *pod install* (since we use React Native as a CocoaPod dependency) and then it worked

Comment: This was the solution! When we upgraded React Native the libRCTAnimation.a went missing (red inside XCode).

So annoying that it works fine in debug but crashes during the release build! Hard to debug.